# Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520 Win8 64-bit Bluetooth Compatibility issues

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, bluetooth, thinkpad

When I try to install the Lenovo Official bluetooth driver on Win8 I get this 
[messages]

(https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/400578_10152802867230198_482164324_n.jpg): [image]

my Bluetooth works on Ubuntu 12.04 but it crashes quite often...

> Can anyone help or supply a solution for this?

Comment: Seems you're having problems with both Bluetooth and WiFi. If the 25th March Win7 x64 BT and 28th March Win8 Intel Wireless LAN drivers do not help you, there's little we can do. I'd advise you to contact Lenovo Support and see what they have to say about it.

Comment: Indeed, problems with both. i'll contact them then. thanx for ur answer!

Comment: this helped:
http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=106987

Comment: So you actually had to use *Linux* to turn on the BT adapter just so the driver installation in Windows would detect it? Looks like Lenovo's drivers have *completely* gone down the drain. Anyway, you should post it as an answer below and accept it so it helps future readers as well. (BTW, did this solve your WiFi issue too?)

Comment: Thanx @Karan ! I was't aware I could answer my own question hehe. And the problem with wireless seems to have been solved by installing the driver for a Lenovo T530, but i'll wait a bit more to mark it as solved. Really, thank you for your comments!

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, self-answering is encouraged on this site because we're trying to gather information here that will help others in the future as well. So if you know it, share it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, finally I found this thread with a "solution": http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=106987

I'm only able to activate Bluetooth under Ubuntu (I only have Ubuntu and Windows). The key step is to leave Bluetooth activated as I leave Ubuntu and then Windows recognizes it. Unfortunately I'm still unable to install the official Lenovo-Broadcom driver. The generic Microsoft driver went active automatically.

I'm glad I can use my Bluetooth again! =)